# Python imports libraries from 3.5, can't find libs from 3.6

Tags: python

I have been learning Python, and noticing that some of my libraries can't be imported (Ubuntu). Having looked at the libraries, I see that some are in the `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/`, and these ones work. The libraries I have been installing recently are in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/`, and these don't work.

I have been aware about the pains of 2 vs 3 paths and such, but in this case my code base ends up having some libs installed and one version folder, and one in the other. When I type `python3 --version`, I get `Python 3.6.8` in response. Thus, it may logically seem that I should be getting errors about the 3.5 libs, not the vise versa.

What's the problem here? How can I solve it?

Comment: This is funny, but the reason why the actual library (gensim) was not getting imported correctly seems to have been my code file being named `gensim.py`. Hilarious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of suitability stop working without virtual environment. If you don’t want to use `pipenv` or `virtualenv` then you can use python’s built in venv module to create a virtual environment:

```sh
$ python3 -m venv myenv
$ source myenv/bin/activate
$ pip install somepackage
```

Since your python3 is set up to python3.6 virtual environment will have python3.6. You can install packages without worrying.

P.S I would recommend you to use pipenv for this.